# Unable to resolve class on Heroku for Spring Boot app

Tags: heroku, gradle, spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot Groovy app to be deployed on Heroku. I was able to successfully do that, but in running it I came across an error in a Spring Jar (spring-social-facebook-web). I downloaded the code from github, added some logging to a class and rebuilt the module.

Then I commented out the reference to the Jar from the **dependencies** section and added a reference to my version of the Jar file:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

The built app has the new Jar file included in it and it builds fine locally. But when I upload it to Heroku, I get compilation errors that the classes contained in the customized Jar aren't being found - each import is marked as *unable to resolve class ...* .

Any idea what is going wrong? I've posted a question to Heroku support but haven't heard anything yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some of your project configuration and a stack trace?  Your a bit sparse on details.

Comment: Operator error! You get into a pattern and don't see clearly. It helps if you add the new jar to the git repo for Heroku to be able to build the software!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time using Heroku and got into the same basic pattern. Unfortunately I didn't store the debug jar I was creating in the git repository. Funny how things start to work when all the pieces are present.